# Adonis2: how to control nestedness in a model

Tags: nested

Hello everyone can somebody tell me how I can control for nestedness in the adonis2 model? Site is nested with forest and I thought this was the way to do it, but if remove everything after method="bray", the result of the model is the same as with perm=how() and plots=plots(). Results:

```
adonis2(formula = bird.dist ~ forest, data = bird_data, permutations = 999, method = "bray")
          Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)    
forest     1   40.215 0.19859 131.58  0.001 ***
Residual 531  162.286 0.80141                  
Total    532  202.501 1.00000                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The code:

````
bird.dist<-vegdist(bird.matrix, method='bray')
bird.div<-adonis2(bird.dist~forest, data=bird_data, permutations = 999, method="bray",
                  perm= how(blocks = bird_data$forest,
                   plots = plots(strata = bird_data$site)))```
````